# Can a let's encrypt SSL certificate also be used for a websocket connection?

Tags: ssl, websocket, lets-encrypt

Our web application has a SSL certificate from letsencrypt

In this app I've build a websocket module to show live data changes in some pages.
During development I didn't notice that my websocket connection was not encrypted, it wasn't necesary.

The websocket server and clients are build according to the guidelines provided by Symfony's [GosWebSocketBundle](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle)

SSL encryption is enabled in an stunnel on the server. I've referenced the same letsencrypt certificates that I use for my website. Whenever the javascript client tries to connect the console shows me this error

> autobahn.min.js:62 WebSocket connection to 'wss://[address]:[port]/'
>   failed: Error in connection establishment:
>   net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

All ports are open and listening according to `netstat -tuplen`

It took me a lot of time to find all this out, How do I manage to get the SSL certificates to make things work without errors?

Comment: Is the address you have in the `wss://[address]:[port]/`  the same hostname that your ssl certificate is generated for ?

Comment: no, it's not. the address I connect to is an IP address. the address that the certificate are generated for all point to this IP address though. do you think changing the IP address to the certificate address will do the trick in solving this?

Comment: yes. - the error says that the address you connect to does not match the name in the certificate - and you have to use the same name that is stated in that certificate, otherwise TLS cannot properly validate the server certificate.

Comment: that's the first thing I'll try tomorrow morning